# Multi dimensional array, with an object for good measure - iteration?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, stdclass

This one is starting to get on my nerves. Still fairly new to arrays and objects.

I need to be able to pull out [id] in the numbered array, plus get access to the lonely snippet_count at the end.

I can do it if there is no top level container array using a foreach $a as $k => $v., (from an earlier SO question) but am struggling a level deeper. Thanks.

```
Array
(
    [snippets] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 123456789
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 123456789
            )
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 123456789
            )
        //and so on
    )
    [snippet_count] => 500
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over just the `snippets` array to get the IDs

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($array['snippets'] as $snippet) {
   $ids[] = $snippet->id;
}

$count = $array['snippet_count'];
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Dagnammit - I was not specifying the array. I'm taking heart that I know what I did wrong. Thanks!